# split flap style animation for iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, animation

I need to show some numbers in my iOS app with an animation like a in a [Split-flap display](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Split-flap_display)

I have found this [video with iOS split flap example](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AkgT_Y1F3oM)

but how to accomplish this? any examples?

thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upon searching, I came across this Flip Clock Animation Tutorial. Which should fit your needs exactly.

[Creating iPad Flip Clock - Core Animation](http://www.voyce.com/index.php/2010/04/10/creating-an-ipad-flip-clock-with-core-animation/)

Answer (score 2):

I resently found a tutorial about animations and matrix transformations.

I think you can accomplish the split-flap with  [this](http://www.odysseyinc.com/Portfolio.html?section=enterthematrix) tutorial.